# SolrJ POJO Annotations

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, solrj

This question is related to SolrJ document as a bean. I have an entity 
that has another entity within it. Could you please tell me how to annotate 
for inner entities? The issue I am facing is the inner entities fields are 
missing while indexing. In the below example, It is just adding Content 
fields and missing out author name and id.

Example:  "Content" is one class that has "Author" as its has-a 
relationship entity.

```
class Content{ 

@Field("uniqueId") 
String id; 

@Field("timeStamp") 
Long timeStamp; 

//What should be the annotation type for this entity? 
Author author; 
} 

class Author{ 
@Field("authorName") 
String authorName; 

@Field("authorId") 
String id; 

}
```

My schema xml is:

```
<field name="uniqueId" type="string" /> 
<field name="timeStamp" type="long" /> 
<field name="authorName" type="string" /> 
<field name="authorId" type="string" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [SOLR-1945](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1945) this is possible since Solr 5.1, by using the `child` property on the `@Field` annotation, as you can see in the [Java docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_1_0/solr-solrj/index.html?overview-summary.html).

In your case it would be:

```
class Content { 
    @Field("uniqueId") 
    String id; 

    @Field("timeStamp") 
    Long timeStamp; 

    @Field(child = true) // You should use this annotation
    Author author; 
}



class Author { 
    @Field("authorName") 
    String authorName; 

    @Field("authorId") 
    String id; 
}
```